# PNG: read the iiNf chunk

Tags: vb.net, png

I have to read the iiNf chunk of .png images with Visual Basic 2012.

So far I have not found any example code how to extract the information.

I have found a tool, called tweekpng - which could be used to extract the iiNf chunk, however this tool does not exist as command line application, so I cant use it for an continuous extraction of the respective information.

Does anyone have an example code on how to extract the information from an png image using VB.Net?

Comment: I am curious about what is the iiNf chunk of a png. I looked through the wikipedia page, where it explains all the chunks of the png, and coudn't find it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: It is someone's private/proprietary chunk, an extension which is allowed by the PNG specification.  "pngtest.c", which is distributed with libpng, demonstrates how to read private chunks.  You'd need to rewrite that in VBASIC.  See the read_user_chunk_callback() function in pngtest.c

Comment: See also [Data format](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5DataRep) in the official specs. VB allows arbitrary  binary reading and seeking, and that is all you need to extract the data part of any chunk. It should be really easy to implement, actually.